# Initialization with Wolfram Demonstrations

Tags: demonstrations

In reading a Wolfram Demonstration, I see:

[image]

Here is what I would like information on:

"Provide any code that must be evaluated before Manipulate. This will automatically be built into the Manipulate in the final notebook version."

Can someone explain what this means? Does it mean that somehow it winds up inside the Manipulate code, maybe using Initialization:>.....

Comment: Without trying it, I'm pretty sure they speak about *initialization cells* anywhere inside your demo notebook.

Comment: I recommend also asking this on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com) - I may get Wolfram person to answer.